# add new fingerprint in TEE Zone

Tags: android, security, fingerprint, zone

Good Morning
I develop an android application similar to Settings application in any device, this application will replace the default setting app in the android system before installing it in the smartwatch that we create in our company.
my problem is that I can't find any way to develop fingerprint features in setting mode to add and delete user fingerprint.
I'm not talking about a simple android app that can be published and downloaded from the play store, but I'm talking about the Settings app that will be integrated inside the device system, so I need to scan the user fingerprint and save it in the TEE secured zone.
I need any advice to help and explain the procedure for me and thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use code from default settings app? https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/biometrics/fingerprint/FingerprintEnrollEnrolling.java

Comment: we are working on default android version without any modifications from any factory like samsung ...., so in the default settings there is no fingerprint settings and we should add it, we already get our fingerprint device to add it in the smartwatch but until now i can't find how to save fingerprint

Comment: I gave you a link to AOSP settings (read without any modifications) to exact file that adds fingerprints

Comment: thank you but i can't really find a way to use it, would you please give me few more details and thank you @DimaRostopira